# How to write to a dummy DataOutputStream without using files?

Tags: java, file, dataoutputstream

I'm using a specific library (unfortunately can't be avoided) that writes some information from a class to a file using a utility function that receives a DataOutputStream as the input.
I would like to get the resulting file's content as a String without actually creating a file and writing into it as the writing can be pretty "taxing" (1000+ lines).
Is this possible to do by using a dummy DataOutputStream or some other method and without resorting to creating a temporary file and reading the result from there?

**P.S:** the final method that actually writes to the DataOutputStream changes from time to time so I would prefer not actually copy-paste it and redo it every time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `java.io.DataOutputStream` wraps around just any other `java.io.OutputStream` (you have to specify an instance in the constructor) I would recommend that you use a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` to collect the data in-memory and get the String of that later with the `.toString()` method.

Example:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream inMemoryOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(inMemoryOutput);

// use dataOutputStream here as intended

// and then get the String data
System.out.println(inMemoryOutput.toString());
```

If the encoding of the collected bytes does not match the system default encoding, you might have to specify a Charset as parameter of the `toString`.